# Rotation off by 90 degrees unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I am trying to rotate my 2d object around my mouse. This is the code I have:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 direction = mousePosition - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
    // Debug.Log(angle);
}
```

My object, which is an arrow, is by default pointing down, so before I start the script I set its z rotation to 90, so it faces right. If I delete the `transform.rotation` line, the angle shown will be right, when my cursor is above it says 90, in the left it says 180 etc. So my question is: Why do I need to add 90 degrees to angle to make this actually work? Why doesn't this version work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Mathf.Atan2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html)(Also see [Wikipedia - Atan2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2))

> Return value is the **angle between the x-axis** [=`Vector3.right`] and a 2D vector starting at zero and terminating at (x,y).

It would work as expected if your arrow by default would point to the right but yours is

> by default pointing down

---

you could simply add the offset rotation on top like

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle + 90);
```

---

Alternatively if you need this for multiple objects with different offsets either use a configurable field like

```
[SerializeField] private float angleOffset;

...

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle + angleOffset);
```

Or you could rotate it manually to face correctly to the right before starting the app and store that default offset rotation like

```
private Quaternion defaultRotation;

private void Awake ()
{
    defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
}
```

and then do

```
transform.rotation = defaultRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
```